# How can this element button be clicked using protractor?

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, protractor

I'm trying to select this button using protractor:

```
<button tabindex="-1" type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" ng-click="$arrowAction(-1, 0)">

 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up">
 </i>

</button>
```

the only unique element in this is `ng-click="$arrowAction(-1, 0)"`

Nothing I have tried works:

```
element(by.css("//button[@ng-click='$arrowAction(-1, 0)']")).click();
```

Comment: Have you tried adding your own custom CSS for that element? Also it looks like your using `by.css` but specifying and `xpath`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`//button[@ng-click='$arrowAction(-1, 0)']` *is not a valid CSS selector*. It actually looks like this is an XPath expression and you meant to use `by.xpath()` locator.

You can though use the partial attribute check instead:

```
$("button[ng-click*=arrowAction]").click();
```

`$` here is a shortcut to `element(by.css(...))`, `*=` means "contains".

Or, do an exact match:

```
$("button[ng-click='$arrowAction(-1, 0)']").click();
```

I still don't like the location technique used in this case, but, given what we have, it is probably the best we can do. Ideally, if you have control over the application code and templates, add a meaningful `id`, `class` or a custom data attribute to uniquely identify the element.

Comment: It works but I get a warning because there are 4 buttons with "arrowAction". if i use $("button[ng-click*=$arrowAction(-1, 0)]").click(); instead I get invalid selector.

Comment: @jmd1002 okay, could you post the HTML representation of all these 4 buttons? Want to see the difference. Thanks.

Comment: <button tabindex="-1" type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" ng-click="$arrowAction(-1, 0)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i></button>  ............... <button tabindex="-1" type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" ng-click="$arrowAction(-1, 1)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i></button>. The only difference is the (-1, 1)